# OleDbException (ACCESS) inner join query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Tables:

```
CS(sid,cid) both int

Courses(id,price) both int


SELECT CS.sid,SUM(Courses.price) as sum FROM CS INNER JOIN Courses ON CS.cid=Courses.id AND CS.sid=@sid GROUP BY CS.sid
```

I want the price `sum of courses of sid=@sid`.
@sid is a parameter of SQLDataSource.

I get this exception:
    An exception of type '`System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Web.dll` but was not handled in user code

```
Additional information: The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 0):

you may need to use WHERE

```
SELECT CS.sid,SUM(Courses.price) as sum FROM CS INNER JOIN Courses ON CS.cid=Courses.id WHERE CS.sid=@sid GROUP BY CS.sid
```

or alternatively this might work too:

```
SELECT CS.sid,SUM(Courses.price) as sum FROM CS INNER JOIN Courses ON CS.cid=Courses.id AND ON CS.sid=@sid GROUP BY CS.sid
```

Comment: you can also try using a different alias instead of sum; for example as Total

Answer (score 0):

SUM is a reserved word and you are trying to select the

```
SUM(Courses.Price) as Sum...
```

the AS SUM is choking. Try changing to

```
SUM(Courses.Price) as SumOfCourses
```

And also, having the named parameter as the same name as the column you are comparing to might be an issue.  I always try to FORCE a differentiation to prevent any possible ambiguous interpretation, such as changing your

```
CS.sid= @sid
```

where @P when I do OleDB is "The Parameter for", so I would have

```
CS.sid= @Psid
```